# Is there a way to overload len() so that I don't have to use an int?

Tags: python

I am creating a class that works with time ranges,

```
class Time_Range:
    """A class that models time ranges."""
    
    def __init__(self, start:str, end:str, time_format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'):
        """Creates a time range.
        
        Parameters:
            start : str - start time.
            end : str - end time.
        """
        start_time = datetime.strptime(start, time_format)
        end_time = datetime.strptime(end, time_format)
        
        if start_time > end_time:
            raise ValueError("End time is before start time.")
        
        self.start = start_time
        self.end = end_time
    
    def __len__(self):
        """Returns the elapsed time in the time range."""
        return self.end - self.start
```

I defined len() to be the time elapsed as a timedelta object, but im getting an error
`"TypeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"`

In my opinion, this is  a perfectly reasonable way to implement len() in this class, but Python won't allow it. Is there a better way to do this? Do I have to resort to writing my own length method?

Comment: `__len__` It is generally used to indicate the length of the container type. It has a clear meaning. Do not use it to indicate other lengths.

Comment: Special aka. magic methods have a defined job within the Python data model. In case of `__len__` it should return an integer. Other special methods (e.g. `__bool__`) can rely on this for their functionality.

Comment: You could perhaps return the elapsed time in milliseconds (an integer)

Comment: @JanWillem I think that's probably the best solution here, only problem is that number could be unreasonably large.

Comment: "In my opinion, this is a perfectly reasonable way ..." But programming isn't about your opinion. It's about communicating with other programmers and with the machine consistently, and everyone *else* has [agreed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) that `len` returns the number of elements of a collection-like object, not a length of time.

Comment: Rename the method `ellapsed()`, `timelen()`, `timedelta()`, or something and stop the non-idiomatic usage of `len()`. Readers of your code will thank you.

Comment: @RyanFolks: Unreasonably large is not an issue for Python, if you do it properly. You can return an `int` number of microseconds (or millis, or seconds, or whatever) by combining the attributes of the `timedelta` into a single `int` value. That said, this should only be done in `__len__` if your class is an iterable that can iterate over that many values; `for t in Time_Range(...):` should produce as many `t`s (presumably `datetime` objects) as `len(Time_Range(...))` claims it contains.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I ended up making a new attribute called time_elapsed that is end-start. I agree that if len() is thought of as one thing in the python community, it should conform.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are trying to fit something that isn't into a class.

If your class has only two methods, one of which is `__init__`, then (in general) it should be a function instead:

```
def time_range(start:str, end:str, time_format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'):
    start_time = datetime.strptime(start, time_format)
    end_time = datetime.strptime(end, time_format)
    
    if start_time > end_time:
        raise ValueError("End time is before start time.")

    return end_time - start_time
```

Especially since you are producing a `TimeDelta` anyway.

Comment: It has more than two methods, I was just trying to do a minimal reproducible example. There is also a __str__ method, and a __sub__ method that prints time ranges and does set difference between them. In addition I have overloaded the initializer.

Comment: Then why not subclass`TimeDelta`?

Comment: I think its fun to write my own code :)